How to convert a PEM PKCS#8 public key into DER/Raw-Binary
I have an EC Public Key (i think it is pkcs#8 PEM but not really sure because i am not much familiar with these terms):
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAE10Hdyc6k1jVb0ex4xYgbmxfF07+PLyuK
PNHsmOjQqm1FDYifXb4xnDrTcjJbzb/y4+zWg1RIsHe3xqdN+zo3QJcm3GwbZp18
CMegoNmpmAP35l9djXMV9cY1cg/iDmbs
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Now i need to convert it into DER.
First i entered the following command:
openssl ec -pubin -pubout -in key.pem -text

and got this output:
read EC key
Public-Key: (384 bit)
pub:
    04:d7:41:dd:c9:ce:a4:d6:35:5b:d1:ec:78:c5:88:
    1b:9b:17:c5:d3:bf:8f:2f:2b:8a:3c:d1:ec:98:e8:
    d0:aa:6d:45:0d:88:9f:5d:be:31:9c:3a:d3:72:32:
    5b:cd:bf:f2:e3:ec:d6:83:54:48:b0:77:b7:c6:a7:
    4d:fb:3a:37:40:97:26:dc:6c:1b:66:9d:7c:08:c7:
    a0:a0:d9:a9:98:03:f7:e6:5f:5d:8d:73:15:f5:c6:
    35:72:0f:e2:0e:66:ec
ASN1 OID: secp384r1
NIST CURVE: P-384

It is exactly what i want, as you can see, that command displays a sequence of HEX-numbers which is exactly what i want.
But when i try to save this output into a file using this command:
openssl ec -pubin -in key.pem -out out.der -outform DER

it saves something different (it just decodes the base64 inside the ---begin-- and ----end---- blocks and saves the result into a file which is not desired for me).
Can anyone help me how to convert that public key into raw-signature/binary and vice versa?
i really need it and besides that, may i know how to convert a raw-signature into a PEM public key like that ?
Thanks in advance.

This is not a PKCS#8 key, but an X.509/SPKI key (PKCS#8 is a format for private keys). If you want to convert the PEM key into a DER key, the second OpenSSL statement is correct, as you can easily verify by loading the resulting byte sequence into an ASN.1/DER parser such as https://lapo.it/asn1js/.

However, you do not seem to need the DER encoded key, but the raw public key in uncompressed format (referred to as pub in the output). This is 97 bytes in size for a secp384r1 key (0x04||) and is located at the end of the DER encoded SPKI key. You therefore only need to use the last 97 bytes of the DER encoded SPKI key.

It's not clear what you want, so maybe I should ask instead what part(s) you don't want? You say the hex-encoded text output is exactly what you want, but if it is, then why aren't you done?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk  Thanks for  your responses. but in case that i have only that 97 bytes, what should i do to convert it into SPKI/x509 format ? I got your point and after decoding the base64 i saw that the last 97-bytes is what i want but i don't know how to do in reverse to convert a 97-bytes key to PEM/SPKI/x509 format ?

@Topaco Thanks for the response, could you please see my above message.

However, there are 23-bytes before that 97-bytes and i think it is a fixed hex numbers and we can put them manually before our own original pub-key, but it would be better if there is any standard command using openssl ?

The prefix is curve-specific, contains length information and algorithm OIDs. If you concatenate this 23 bytes prefix with a 97 bytes uncompressed key for secp384r1 you will get a DER encoded X.509/SPKI key for secp384r1, see here. As far as I know, the direct conversion DER/SPKI <-> uncompressed key is not supported by OpenSSL.

@Topaco I got my answer through this sentence You therefore only need to use the last 97 bytes of the DER encoded SPKI key, can you post the answer and let me mark it as Answer!

Sure, I've summarized my comments in an answer.


Can anyone help me how to convert that public key into
raw-signature/binary...

The posted key is a PEM encoded key in X.509/SPKI format for curve secp384r1. This can be converted into a DER encoded key with the posted OpenSSL statement:
openssl ec -pubin -in key.pem -out out.der -outform DER

This conversion corresponds to the removal of header, footer, all line breaks and Base64 decoding of the rest.
At the end of the DER encoded key is the public key in uncompressed format (referred to as pub in the OpenSSL printout via -text option). The uncompressed format for secp384r1 has a length of 97 bytes (0x04|<x>|<y>; <x> and <y> are the coordinates of the EC point, each 384/8=48 bytes long).
Therefore, to extract the uncompressed key from the DER encoded key, only the last 97 bytes need to be taken.

...and vice versa?

The first 23 bytes contain length information and algorithm OIDs. This byte sequence is curve-specific and its length information specifies a key in uncompressed format (i.e. the byte sequence of a different curve and/or a key in compressed format would be different). It can therefore be used as a prefix to convert a secp384r1 key in uncompressed format into a DER encoded key in X.509/SPKI format.

...but it would be better if there is any standard command using
openssl...

OpenSSL does not (to my knowledge) support the direct conversion of PEM/DER encoded public keys into the uncompressed (or compressed) format or vice versa.

For the sake of completeness: With the option -conv_form compressed in the OpenSSL statement above, the compressed format (<a>|<x>, with <a> = 0x02 for even <y> and <0x03> for odd <y>) can be used instead of the uncompressed format. This has a length of 49 bytes for secp384r1.
A DER (or PEM) encoded key can be easily analyzed when decoded with an ASN.1/DER parser, e.g. here for the posted key.
